# My site crashes IE8, but only when accessed on the server

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8

I've been working on this site and checking in IE8, Chrome, FF and Safari. Everything has been fine throughout.

However, now that I've uploaded the site to a server, it crashes IE8 every time - what is going on?!

Link: http://www.oxfordsoundhire.com/morland

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

Link: http://www.oxfordsoundhire.com/morland

It's working on Internet Explorer 10

Answer (score 0):

I think it's to do with this js file: http://www.oxfordsoundhire.com/morland/js/carouFredSel.html

It's not actually at that location, but instead of just returning blank, your server is returning a full 404.html file, and the opening `"<HTML..."` is making it break.